# Rename assembly-generated uberjar in SBT

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly, uberjar

How to rename and move an uberjar generated with SBT assembly plugin?

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

My assemblyMergeStrategy(for META-INF removal):

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
   case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
   case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

It generates something like :

```
target/scala-2.12/my-project-assembly-0.1.jar
```

which I would like to able to automatically rename (and generate in another directory) with a consistent name (without the need of a separate script).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a bit of documentation in project's [page](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). There, you can find the keys you can rewrite for the `assembly` task.

The ones you are searching for are `assemblyJarName` and `assemblyOutputPath`. Then, your project build should look something like:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    ...
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "myName.jar",
    assemblyOutputPath in assembly := "...",
    ...
  )
```